# RSA Encryption of string with known modulus and exponent in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security, encryption, rsa

I need to implement RSA encryption of  user credentials(password mainly) entered by user in iOS app with defined Modulus and Exponent.

Could you please provide me any example code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you'll end up using OpenSSL directly but take a look at the following reference beforehand: [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157)

[Using OpenSSL and RSA](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2002/Mar/msg01660.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have gone through this example but not able to set own modulus and exponent that I already have.

Comment: Any solution found for this question ?